# Деплой приложения на nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, развертывание

Как быть, если ты фрилансер и делаешь большую часть проектов на ноде. С пхп все просто, арендовал хостинг, прикрутил домен (с этим нет проблем), настройка 5 минут и все. Есть ли возможность сделать подобное с нодой?

Comment: а в чем проблема так же арендовать хостинг и прикрутить домен?